# MSBuild or TFSBuild Conditional for One Project?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, setup-deployment, msbuild-4.0

I have a long-time-to-build (setup) project in a Visual Studio 2010 Solution. It is set not to build in the Solution configuration. That way, when a developer builds locally they are not burdened with waiting for the setup to compile in Visual Studio.

However, I am looking for a way to change the configuration in tfsbuild or msbuild files so whenever things are built on the server, the setup project is always built, regardless of what the setting might be when a developer checks in their solution. TFS 2008 is the source control system but just a plain Server 2008 (with devenv fully installed) is the build server.

All clues appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new configuration in your solution, named e.g. `Release_Setup`, that way you have seperate configurations for developer and setup build (note that developers can choose that config and build everything locally if they so choose, which is quite nice when all Build agents are busy and you want to check that everything's fine).

In `Solution Properties->Configuration Properties->Configuration` you can even tell it to build the normal Release Configuration and still choose which projects to build and which to exclude.

Hope this helps. I haven't actually tested this, so please try it and comment back if there are any problems or this doesn't solve your specific question.

Comment: or even just set it to build on the release target and not debug?

Comment: @James The developer will want/have to compile for Release as well to be sure everything works fine before committing any changes. Though this may be done on the Server as well via Gated Checkin, it may still not be desired that the Setup is built in that case.

Comment: I tried lots of different tactics, and in the end came back to doing as Sven suggested, adding a new config. So developers use the solution config 'debug' and the build server uses the solution config 'ci'. 'ci' has the projects included that run extensive tests and MSI creation. Thanks!